# Visual Studio 2008 Create Word 2007 Template Project Crashes

Tags: visual-studio-2008, templates, vsto, office-2007

I've got this weird crashing happening when creating a C# Word 2007 Template Project in Visual Studio 2008. The IDE tells me that it's creating the project (it does create the solution and C# vsproj as well as the dotx and cs files). Then the IDE just crashes - no errors, messages, etc. When I try *devenv /SafeMode* it still doesn't work. I've also tried *devenv /log* but I don't really see any smoking guns.

I have VS2008 SP1 and VSTO 3.0 SP1 installed.

Anybody know why this is occurring or more importantly, how I can get it to stop?